# $\sigma$-algebra generated by the function

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Suppose function $f:\Omega \rightarrow (\Omega', Y)$ measurable. Define $$X = \sigma(\{f^{-1}(K) : K \in Y\})$$ Prove that for any $A \in X$ and any $w_1, w_2\in \Omega$ with $f(w_1) = f(w_2)$, either $w_1, w_2 \in A$ or $w_1, w_2 \in A^{\complement}$.

I was trying to establish that there exists some $D \in Y$ such that $A = f^{-1}(D)$, then the result is trivial. Is it the case that there is such a set $D$?

Comment: Yes. https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Pre-Image_Sigma-Algebra_on_Domain_is_Sigma-Algebra

Comment: @Max I am not sure how this helps me, as I already know that $X$ is a sigma algebra

Comment: Don't apply this to $X$. Apply this to $Z=\{f^{-1}(K):K\in Y\}$ aka the preimage of the sigma algebra $Y$. Then $Z$ is already a sigma-algebra, so $Z=X$.  (Unless $Y$ itself is not a sigma algebra, then the answer is no, there is no such $D$ -- take $f$ be identity).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to prove that
$$X=\{f^{-1}(K):K\in Y\}.$$
But this is not difficult, since
1.
$$\Omega =f^{-1}(\Omega’)\in X$$
2. $$f^{-1}(A^c) = (f^{-1}(A))^c\in X$$
3. Let be $I\neq\emptyset$ countable and $A_i = f^{-1}(B_i)$ for every $i\in I$ pairwise disjoint, then
$$
\bigcup_{i\in I} A_i = \bigcup_{i\in I} f^{-1}(B_i) =  f^{-1}(\bigcup_{i\in I} B_i)\in X
$$
Thus $\{f^{-1}(K):K\in Y\}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra (yielding $X=\{f^{-1}(K):K\in Y\}$, as $X$ is the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing $\{f^{-1}(K):K\in Y\}$) and every $A\in X$ is of this form. With that follows also the claim.

Answer (score 0):

As others have shown, the result is very simple if you know that the inverse image of a $\sigma$-algebra is a $\sigma$-algebra.

But I would like to suggest a different approach I find instructive.

For any $\omega_1, \omega_2 \in \Omega$ such that $f(\omega_1) = f(\omega_2)$, let
$$Z = \{ A \subset \Omega \,:\, \{\omega_1,\omega_2\} \subset A \text{ or } \{\omega_1,\omega_2\} \subset A^c\}.$$
It is very easy to check that $Z$ is a $\sigma$-algebra that contains
$$\{ f^{-1}(K) \,:\, K \in Y \}.$$
And $X$ is the smallest $\sigma$-algebra that contains this set.